# Handling an Array in Java (two columns)

Tags: java

For instance suppose I have the following `String`

```
String S = "5,a\n" +
           "6,b\n" +
           "9,a";
```

The format is always the same - one digit, then comma, then one character and then line end character.

For looping each row in String I use

```
for(String a : S.split("\\n")){}
```

I want to learn the character with highest amount, when grouped by character. For Instance, there is only one "b", so value is 6; whereas "a" has two lines, so its value is 5 + 9 = 14. Since 14 is maximum here, I want to find out "a" and 14 and save them in variables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you are right. Sorry for typo. I've corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like below :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
        String S = "5,a\n" +
           "6,b\n" +
           "9,a";

        String[] lines = S.split("\\n");
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for( String t : lines )
        {
            String[] e = t.split(",");
            Integer digit = Integer.parseInt(e[0]);
            String c = e[1];
            if ( map.get(c) != null )
            {
                Integer val = map.get(c);
                val += digit;
                map.put( c, val );
            }
            else
            {
                map.put( c, digit );
            }

        }

        int max = 0;
        String maxKey = null;
        for ( String k : map.keySet() )
        {
            if ( map.get(k) > max )
            {

                max = map.get(k);
                maxKey = k;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The maximum key is : " + maxKey );
        System.out.println("The maximum value is : " + max );
    }
```

Output is :

```
The maximum key is : a
The maximum value is : 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap to store each pair, with the letter as the key.  If the entry doesn't exist, `put` the first number.   If it exists, `get` the entry and add the number, and then `put` the sum.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String S = "5,a\n" + "6,b\n" + "9,a";

        String maxKey = null;
        int maxVal = 0;

        Map<String, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();
        for (String a : S.split("\\n")) {
            String[] split = a.split(",");
            int value = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            String key = split[1];

            if (sums.containsKey(key)) {
                sums.put(key, sums.get(key) + value);
            } else {
                sums.put(key, value);
            }

            if (sums.get(key) > maxVal) {
                maxVal = sums.get(key);
                maxKey = key;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Max key: " + maxKey + ", Sum: " + maxVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After finishing my answer,  I found that many similar answers have been posted out :). Anyway, my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String S = "5,a\n6,b\n9,a";
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String highestAmountChar = "";
    int highestAmount = 0;
    for (String str : S.split("\\n")) {
        String[] amountChar = str.split(",");
        if (map.get(amountChar[1]) == null) {
            map.put(amountChar[1], Integer.parseInt(amountChar[0]));
        } else {
            map.put(amountChar[1], map.get(amountChar[1]) + Integer.parseInt(amountChar[0]));
        }
        if (highestAmount < map.get(amountChar[1])) {
            highestAmount = map.get(amountChar[1]);
            highestAmountChar = amountChar[1];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The character " + highestAmountChar + " has highest amount " + highestAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this without using HashMap or any collection for that matter

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String S = "5,a\n" +
            "6,b\n" +
            "9,a";
        // Separate the string by number and letter
        String[] separated = S.split("\\n");
        // Create a new array to store the letters only
        char[] letters = new char[separated.length];
        // Write the letter
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            letters[i] = separated[i].charAt(2);
        }
        // Sort them haha
        Arrays.sort(letters);

        // And now find out which letter is repeated most
        // Store the first letter
        char previous = letters[0];
        // Make it the most repeated one for now
        char mostRepeated = letters[0];
        int count = 1;
        int maxCount = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
            // since the array is sorted if the actual letter is the same as the previous one then keep counting
            if (letters[i] == previous)
                count++;
            else {
                if (count > maxCount) {
                    mostRepeated = letters[i - 1];
                    maxCount = count;
                }
                previous = letters[i];
                count = 1;
            }     
        }
        char answer = count > maxCount ? letters[letters.length-1] : mostRepeated;
        // Once you get the letter now just add all the numbers that goes with it
        int sum = 0;
        for (String s:separated) {
            if (s.charAt(2) == answer) {
                sum += Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        // Print the result by printing the letter and it sum
    }
}
```